# get_posts array value get_the_ID not working

Tags: wordpress

I have set up a post_type step.  In it there is an ACF field that allows for one relationship to another post.

So from the other post I am trying to retrieve all the step posts that have the ID of the current post (from a single post page).
The search if for at meta-value in the post-options table for word press (which is a string field by definition).

I have this query

```
$steps = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'step',
    'meta_query' => array(
     array(
        'key' => 'step_goal', // name of custom field
        'value' => '"' . get_the_ID() . '"',
      //'value' => "439", 
    'compare' => 'LIKE'
    )
)
));
```

I have used vardump(get_the_ID()) and it returns 439(init) as it is a post ID.

I have check the value of get_the_ID() and it is 439

If I run the script using the '"' . get_the_ID() . '"' as value the query does not work.
If I use it using the value "439" it works.
If I run the script using the get_the_ID()  as value it works but later may cause problems on an id such as 4391 .

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you

Comment: Where are you using this code? Also, where did you check the value of `get_the_ID()`? Did you check in the line directly before the `get_posts` function?

Comment: I am using it on a single post page,  I did check for the value of get_the_ID()  by <pre><?php echo 'value is "' . get_the_ID() . '"'; ?></pre>  which returns value is "439"

Comment: Can you add this in the line directly before the `$steps = get_posts(array(...` and updated your question to show us exactly what it outputs? `var_dump(get_the_ID());`

Comment: it returns int(439)   and is what Josh below mentioned might be the problem.

Comment: Are you trying to match a number? If so, why are you using `LIKE` - that is a partial string comparison? Can you explain exactly what you are trying to achieve, so we can help you get there? :)

Comment: This is a query to get a related post from the post type "step"  I have created a field in step called step_goal  where the input is a single post id from a drop down list.  So this would be a reverse query  (I am searching all step post that have the value of step_goal the same as the current ID.  I am using examples where that field is an array but I will only ever have 1. Is that where my problem lies?

Comment: it is searching the meta-value of the post which are all strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing an exact match on numbers, so `LIKE` is the wrong comparison - that only works on **strings** and it also does **partial matches** (so "439" would also match "4391", "1439" etc).

If you are trying to look up a value using a **numeric exact match**, you need to use:

- comparison type: `=` (this is the default comparison so it's not necessary to include it)
- `'type' => 'NUMERIC'`

Try this code below - it's untested because I don't have your CPTs etc, but it should work!

```
$steps = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'step',
    'meta_query' => array(
         array(
            'key' => 'step_goal', // name of custom field
            'value' => get_the_ID(),
            'type' => 'NUMERIC',
        )
    )
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, I'm going to assume that 439 is actually the correct value that you want to use and that this is a formatting issue.

Have you tried just using `get_the_ID()` without escaping it from the parenthesis?
Currently it's set as 
`'"' . get_the_ID() . '"'`
which will return as
`'"439"'`

What if you try `"' . get_the_ID() . '"`? That will return as `"439"`.

Comment: I tried that and still nothing found . I think it is right as all the examples I have seen are showing it that way, I think it is appending the value of get_the_ID with quotes.

Comment: Is it possible that the value you're searching for is set as an int in the database and not a string?

Comment: "*Without more information, I'm going to assume that...*" That's why the guidelines say to  [answer well-asked questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), so we don't have to guess at what the OP might want, and more often than not get it wrong :)  If you need more information (as is the case here) it is better to ask in the comments first so that the OP can edit the question to have all the information needed and make it both answerable and also useful for other users with similar questions :)